# c# load image into PictureBox without slowing down UI

Tags: c#, gdi+, picturebox

I am trying to load 720x480 bitmaps into a picturebox very quickly and while loading the images into the picturebox, the UI of my application slows down considerably.
Is there any way around it ?
I read that when using a backgroundworker, I cannot load the image into the picturebox control in the DoWork event ..

What are my options ?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using the Profiler to see specifically where the most expensive calls are coming from first, so you know which problem you're facing.

Comment: Thanks. I receive the image in the form of a byte array then reconstruct a bitmap from it, then display it in the picturebox by assigning the image property of the picturebox to it. If I comment out the part that actually assigns the Bitmap to the PictureBox, the UI is not sluggish at all.

Comment: Having similar issue. Have all (few and small) images pre-loaded, clicking on the PictureBox cycles through the images. If I click moderately fast the PictureBox 'misses' some of my clicks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on from where you are getting image. If it comes from network drive or from web or database then `BackgroundWorker` will definitely help you. Get the image in `DoWork` handler and assign the image to `PictureBox` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.

Comment: Thanks. I receive the image in the form of a byte array then reconstruct a bitmap from it, then display it in the picturebox by assigning the image property of the picturebox to it.

Comment: then please try `BackgroundWorker` and construct image in `DoWork` handler and pass this constructed image to `RunWorkerComplatedHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [PictureBox.LoadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/221dw5x0.aspx) method.